# Android how to parse CDATA TAG?

Tags: android

I have below String i want to parse it !!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:GetDrinksResponse xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <return xsi:type="xsd:xml">
                <Details>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <Name>drinks1</Name>
                    <lid>1</lid>
                    <LName><![CDATA[ 151-Proof Rum]]></LName>
                    <lamount><![CDATA[12000]]></lamount>
                    <dmid>1</dmid>
                    <mname><![CDATA[Apple Juice]]></mname>
                    <mamount><![CDATA[2323]]></mamount>
                    <inid></inid>
                    <inName><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inName>
                    <inamount><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inamount>
                    <Glass>HighBall Glass</Glass>
                    <Directions>33</Directions>
                    <Condiment>22</Condiment>
                </Details>
                <Details>
                    <id>2</id>
                    <Name>Drnks2</Name>
                    <lid></lid>
                    <LName><![CDATA[ 101-Proof Bourbon]]></LName>
                    <lamount><![CDATA[12000]]></lamount>
                    <dmid>2</dmid>
                    <mname><![CDATA[Apple Juice]]></mname>
                    <mamount><![CDATA[25000]]></mamount>
                    <inid></inid>
                    <inName><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inName>
                    <inamount><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inamount>
                    <Glass>Cocktail Glass</Glass>
                    <Directions>ss</Directions>
                    <Condiment>sd</Condiment>
                </Details>
                <Details>
                    <id>3</id>
                    <Name>Gimlet</Name>
                    <lid></lid>
                    <LName><![CDATA[ 151-Proof Rumsssssssss]]></LName>
                    <lamount><![CDATA[1s]]></lamount>
                    <dmid>3</dmid>
                    <mname><![CDATA[Apple Juice]]></mname>
                    <mamount><![CDATA[1]]></mamount>
                    <inid></inid>
                    <inName><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inName>
                    <inamount><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inamount>
                    <Glass>Regular</Glass>
                    <Directions>sadasd</Directions>
                    <Condiment>asd</Condiment>
                </Details>
                <Details>
                    <id>4</id>
                    <Name>Drinlks3</Name>
                    <lid></lid>
                    <LName><![CDATA[ 151-Proof Rumsssssssssssss]]></LName>
                    <lamount><![CDATA[12000]]></lamount>
                    <dmid>4</dmid>
                    <mname><![CDATA[Apple Juice]]></mname>
                    <mamount><![CDATA[2323]]></mamount>
                    <inid></inid>
                    <inName><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inName>
                    <inamount><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inamount>
                    <Glass>Regular</Glass>
                    <Directions>33</Directions>
                    <Condiment>22</Condiment>
                </Details>
                <Details>
                    <id>5</id>
                    <Name>Dr Abu Julianah</Name>
                    <lid></lid>
                    <LName><![CDATA[ 151-Proof Rum]]></LName>
                    <lamount><![CDATA[sss]]></lamount>
                    <dmid>5</dmid>
                    <mname><![CDATA[Apple Juice]]></mname>
                    <mamount><![CDATA[2323]]></mamount>
                    <inid></inid>
                    <inName><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inName>
                    <inamount><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inamount>
                    <Glass>Cocktail Glass</Glass>
                    <Directions>33</Directions>
                    <Condiment>22</Condiment>
                </Details>
                <Details>
                    <id>6</id>
                    <Name>Dr Abu</Name>
                    <lid></lid>
                    <LName><![CDATA[ 151-Proof Rum]]></LName>
                    <lamount><![CDATA[12000]]></lamount>
                    <dmid>6</dmid>
                    <mname><![CDATA[Apple Juicesssssss]]></mname>
                    <mamount><![CDATA[sddddddd]]></mamount>
                    <inid></inid>
                    <inName><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inName>
                    <inamount><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inamount>
                    <Glass></Glass>
                    <Directions>33</Directions>
                    <Condiment>22</Condiment>
                </Details>
                <Details>
                    <id>7</id>
                    <Name>Gimlet</Name>
                    <lid></lid>
                    <LName><![CDATA[ 1Testliquers]]></LName>
                    <lamount><![CDATA[12000]]></lamount>
                    <lid></lid>
                    <LName><![CDATA[sdffds]]></LName>
                    <lamount><![CDATA[dsdf]]></lamount>
                    <dmid>7</dmid>
                    <mname><![CDATA[Apple Juiceaaaaaaaaa]]></mname>
                    <mamount><![CDATA[aaaaaaaaaaaaa]]></mamount>
                    <dmid>8</dmid>
                    <mname><![CDATA[7-Up]]></mname>
                    <mamount><![CDATA[2323]]></mamount>
                    <inid>1</inid>
                    <inName><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inName>
                    <inamount><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inamount>
                    <inid>2</inid>
                    <inName><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inName>
                    <inamount><![CDATA[]]>
                    </inamount>
                    <Glass>Regular</Glass>
                    <Directions></Directions>
                    <Condiment></Condiment>
                </Details>
            </return>
        </ns1:GetDrinksResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

here is my code and response is above Xml String...........
How to parser in and please give me Handler Class................

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();


                    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

                    ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
                    xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

                    xr.parse(new InputSource(response.toString()));

                    ParsedExampleDataSet parsedExampleDataSet = myExampleHandler
                            .getParsedData();
```

Exception:::

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at DrinkParser.executeRequest(DrinkParser.java:105)
    at DrinkParser.<init>(DrinkParser.java:64)
    at DrinkParser.main(DrinkParser.java:149)
```

Comment: What code did you write to parse the XML? What errors did you get?

Comment: filenot found exception and can read any tag and i parse from server so why FilenotFound also check this String come proprely...........

Comment: see all i update my question....................

Comment: Can you plz provide me an example for CADTA XML parsing in Android i'm new to Android thanks i want this type of example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup Problem is solved...............

```
factory.setCoalescing(true);
```

DocumentFactory and CDATA is removed and parsing is as like as Normal XML File................

Comment: I don't find method factory.setCoalescing(true);
Can you help me.