# Can't Parse Tag <![CDATA[]]> in Android Version 2.1

Tags: android, xml

Let's go to the point..

I make an Android application which target is Google APIs (Platform 2.2). 
I want to parse the XML File which comes from the REST API.

The XML file likes this:

```
<title>EARTH WIND & FIRE Live in Concert</title>
```

I store that output in my String variable, which I can use later and since the output is in XML, I use XML Parser class of course. 
And as you can see, since the rule of XML format doesn't allow the naked character, in this case my '&' character, it will show:

```
<title>EARTH WIND &amp; FIRE Live in Concert</title>
```

So I change that character with this method: `xml.replaceAll("&amp;", "<![CDATA[&]]>");`
xml is String and I replace my `&amp;` with `<![CDATA[&]]>` tag.
And I follow this: [Android how to parse CDATA TAG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448496/android-how-to-parse-cdata-tag) 
It says that I must use **dbf.setCoalescing(true);**

Everything goes fine and in my TextView shows the words **EARTH WIND & FIRE Live in Concert**. The ampersand character (&) is shown in my emulator (Platform 2.2).
But, when I try it in the device (Platform 2.1), it will show only **EARTH WIND**.
And I make the new emulator Google APIs (Platform 2.1), it shows **EARTH WIND** too.

Does anyone here face the same problem with me?? 
Is there any compatibility issue with the XML Parser or the `<![CDATA[]]>` tag in Android??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

In String.xml in resouces folder

```
    <string name="my_string"><![CDATA[Please put Your long text here ]]></string>
```

if you want to access this string for textview:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/my_string"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```